# AngularJs: Loop through / return all states in $stateProvider / ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

this is a silly question, but should I wish to return all instances of `$stateProvider.state` in my app.js (my AngularJS config file) how would I go about this? For example when I used the `ngRoute` I could do something like this in my `.run()` block:

```
.run(function ($route) {

     var someArray = [];
     angular.forEach($route.routes, function (route, path) {
          if (route.someKey) {
            console.log(path); // do something with route.someKey!!!
            someArray.push(route.someKey);
          }
   });
});
```

However, in my app I am using the `ui-router` and I can't do something similar with `$state`? I'm currently reading up on this but if anyone has a quick answer let me know!

Comment: What would you want to do in this "do something" ? Are you just trying to retrieve the current state ?

Comment: I would be checking the value of route.somekey and then performing an action like making an array and then using this later to determine access

Comment: Oh, like having the history of the user navigation ? I love the idea. You could do this by using the $scope.$on("$stateChangeSucess")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it! `$state.get()` works! I must have missed this before in the docs!

`$state.get()` will output an object array, I run `console.log($state.get);` and I get:

```
[
  {
    "name": "",
    "url": "^",
    "views": null,
    "abstract": true
  },
  {
    "abstract": true,
    "template": "<ui-view/>",
    "name": "app"
  },
  {
    "url": "/login",
    "templateUrl": "login/views/login.html",
    "controller": "LoginCtrl",
    "publicAccess": true,
    "name": "app.login"
  },
  {
    "abstract": true,
    "url": "/home",
    "templateUrl": "home/views/home-wrapper.html",
    "controller": "HomeCtrl",
    "name": "app.loggedInHome"
  }
]
```